# Why is my Windows partition locked on Xubuntu?

Tags: windows, boot-partition

The partition itself works fine. It can boot to Windows. But when I try to access it from Xubuntu, I can mount it and see the files but I can't save anything on it.
I have another NTFS partition (Backup) with all my media files and it works just fine.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

[image]

Comment: did you turn off fast startup in Windows? Did you shut down Windows properly? How is the drive being mounted?

Comment: I can't remember if fast startup is enabled. What would that have to do with this? 
Win closed normally.
It's mounted just by clicking on it.

Comment: when fast startup is enabled, windows doesn't ever really shut down; instead it just hibernates. This means that NTFS disks will still have a "dirty bit" set (meaning that Windows wasn't fully shut down properly) , and therefore Linux will not modify them for fear of breaking something. If you want to use the same NTFS disk in Linux and Windows, you have to disable fast startup.